# NameError in nested comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this code in a file

```
class Sudoku(dict):
    COLUMNS = [
        {(x, y) for y in xrange(9)} for x in xrange(9)
    ]
```

When I run `python broken.py`, I get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\broken.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Sudoku(dict):
  File "U:\broken.py", line 3, in Sudoku
    {(x, y) for y in xrange(9)} for x in xrange(9)
  File "U:\broken.py", line 3, in <setcomp>
    {(x, y) for y in xrange(9)} for x in xrange(9)
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I don't really see the problem here. Isn't `x` defined in the comprehension?

---

What's stranger is how this seems to execute without an error when pasted directly into the python interpreter...

---

**EDIT**: This works if I use a list comprehension rather than a set comprehension

Comment: Just to make it clear: could you give the *exact* expected output? I'm just wondering if that's exactly what you want or if will you perform some more magic later.

Comment: @MichałGórny Any non-error output would be good here...

Comment: Err, I'm just wondering if you exactly want sets-in-a-list. That seems a bit non-symmetrical :).

Comment: This is very odd. It seems to be a very specific problem that occurs when using a nested set comprehension as a static member variable. All other combinations I have tried work, just not this particular combination. Dare I say a bug in Python? Gasp!

Comment: It works fine on Python 3.2 (replacing `xrange` with `range`). It looks like a 2.7 bug (in set comprehensions backport).

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: yep, I'm on 2.7 here

Comment: I can reproduce this probelm with Python 2.7: It works in IPython and gives the exception when executed as a script.

Comment: Even worse - if there _is_ a global `x`, it will use that value instead of the one from the list comprehension.

Comment: The problem is to do with the comprehension being inside the class definition.  I suspect people seeing the code work in the interpreter are just trying the comprehension, not the class definition.

Comment: Actually, using a 2.7 interpreter, it breaks as well. Make sure you include the full class definition, not just the line with the comprehension. The problem obviously is that the local variable `x` doesn't get transported into the short-hand set comprehension. I'd file it as a bug; see what happens.

Comment: This was a bug now resolved, update your python version. [Issue 11796](http://bugs.python.org/issue11796).

Comment: @mg: That bug seems to refer to something different - I'm not trying to refer to any class-level variable here.

Comment: @Eric: you are right, I was thinking that the outer list comprehension set the `x` variable in the class block. It is not, a list comprehension creates a new scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've filed a bug [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue18110). This is <del>still broken</del> by design in python 2.7.5.

From the bug report:

> In Python 2, list comprehensions don't have their own scope, so the `x` in your initial example lives at class scope.  However, the set comprehension *does* have its own scope.  By design, a variable defined at class scope is not visible to inner scopes inside that class.
>
> In Python 3, this works because the list comprehension has its own scope.

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess, but Python set comprehensions were introduced with Python 2.7 and 3.0: would you happen to use an older version to execute your script, and a recent one as your interpreter ?

---

After looking at [this section](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html?highlight=enclosing%20scope#naming-and-binding) of the Python documentation, I see no explanation for this behavior. Furthermore, the fact that it works with list comprehension clearly show that it is not a scope issue.

I see only two possible reasons:

- A bug in the set comprehensions implementation
- The use of an anterior Python version which does not support set comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I have no idea why your code is not working, however, the following works and gives you what you want:

```
class Sudoku(dict):
    COLUMNS = [
        set([(x, y) for y in xrange(9)]) for x in xrange(9)
    ]
```

Maybe some of the python gurus on this site can enlighten us as to why your code snippet fails.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could give a theoretical explanation, but this works:

```
class Sudoku(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.COLUMNS = [
            {(x, y) for y in xrange(9)} for x in xrange(9)
            ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Sudoku()
    print s.COLUMNS
```

Comment: i may be talking out of my a$$, but perhaps trying to define COLUMNS as a static member of the class makes the set comprehension loose scope and check for x in the global variables list (which does not make sense to me anyway you look at it). Perhaps report as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this it what you really want:

```
[[{x:y} for x in xrange(9)] for y in xrange(9)]
```

Comment: There is nothing "apriori" wrong with the OP's set comprehension. If you cut it and paste it into an interpreter, it gives the expected answer.

Comment: My interpreter raised a SyntaxError, thats why I thought there is something else wrong. So I posted this answer, which works on my machine. Then I found out that it is just because I'm still using 2.6 :)