# Loop Order in Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does reversing the order of loops in this comprehension yield a different result when used with a comprehension filter?

```
print len([cell for row in cells for cell in row])
print len([cell for cell in row for row in cells])
print len([cell for row in cells for cell in row if cell.rect.collidepoint(pos)])
print len([cell for cell in row for row in cells if cell.rect.collidepoint(pos)])
```

prints:

```
192
192
1
0
```

Comment: Loops are nested from left to right, so the first `for` is the outer loop. That means either `row` or `cells` needs to be defined before the loop runs for the comprehension to work. What are the contents of those variables?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The values leaked from the first comprehension, which does execute!

Comment: @Eric: Quite possibly, and I already voted for your answer. But without further context it is still just speculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running this code in a fresh interpreter:

```
>>> cells = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> [cell for cell in row for row in cells]
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

It works in your code because something's defined a `row` variable. But what?

***in python 2.x*, *list* comprehensions leak local variables** (generator, set, and dictionary comprehensions, or 3's list comprehensions, do not)

In the following:

```
>>> [cell for row in cells for cell in row]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> row
[4, 5, 6]
>>> cell
6
```

`cell` and `row` are added to the local scope. When you run the next test case, you're unintentionally using this old value of `row`:

```
>>> [cell for cell in row for row in cells ]
[4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```

This is only true of *list* comprehensions *in python 2.x*.

One way to avoid being caught out by this is to use `list(... for x in ...)` instead of `[... for x in ...]`.

Comment: This can sometimes lead to some [very peculiar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12259251/102441) problems